# Is it good to use for all $\delta$ there exists $\epsilon$?

Tags: real-analysis, notation

Logically, the following two definitions are exactly the same:

1. For all $\epsilon >0$, there exist $\delta >0$ such that if $0<\vert x-a\vert<\delta$, then $\vert f(x)-L\vert<\epsilon$.
2. For all $\delta >0$, there exist $\epsilon >0$ such that if $0<\vert x-a\vert<\epsilon$, then $\vert f(x)-L\vert<\delta$.

But would people say that the second one follows a "bad notation", a "hard-to-read notation", "less-elegant notation", or an "unconventional notation"? I am trying to make the readers happy.

Comment: It's just a convention. Do you have a good reason to break the convention?

Comment: @BenjaminWang In my second part of the proof I am using epsilon as a small number. But at the end I found out that I had to add some definitions to the first part, which is similar to the definition (2) I wrote above. That is, if I don't want to change all the symbols in the second part and I want all my letters to be consistent, then I would have to use the definition (2) instead of the standard (1).

Comment: In which case, can you keep (2) but replace $\epsilon$ with another Greek letter. I recommend $\eta$. Even that is much better than (2). I don't know what your proof is, so cannot give an absolute answer.

Comment: You can also use $\epsilon', \epsilon^*, \epsilon_0$, etc. so that it still helpfully suggests that we are referencing the epsilon-delta definition of limit.

Comment: It's such an ingrained convention it would throw everyone off.  It'd be likes say "let's use the notation $\frac mn$ to mean $m$ multiplies by $n$ so $6 = \frac 23$ and $\frac 4{16}=\frac 88 = 64$.  you can do it and it's consistent and there's nothing wrong with it.... but WTF man....

Comment: Logically of course letters and symbols can be used as you please. But anyway, atleast my opinion is that certain greek letters "always come in pairs/triples", like $\alpha,\beta, (\gamma)$ or $\mu,\nu$ or $\epsilon, \delta$ or $\xi,\eta, \zeta$ or $\theta, \phi, \psi$. Basically, it would be weird to break up these pairs and switch them around amongst themselves. If you need a different symbol to signify a small number, use something like $\epsilon', \tilde{\epsilon}$, or use another greek letter. Of course without anymore specifics, we can't really say what's "better".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, people would object. Although the choice of variable name doesn't matter mathematically, it can still be *helpful* or *misleading*. There is a general convention around the use of that particular pair of variables, and going against it will only confuse readers.

(Granted, every so often there is a good reason to go against such a convention ... but that tends to be pretty rare.)